# Rails MonkeyPatch changes not being picked up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, monkeypatching

I'm trying to 'MonkeyPatch' [this](https://github.com/jjeffus/SaasySimple/blob/master/app/controllers/saasy_simple/subscriptions_controller.rb) controller in my implementation so that it can handle a third parameter ('productname').

The original activate method in the gem reads

```
def activate
  if Digest::MD5.hexdigest(params["security_data"] + SaasySimple.config.secret) == params["security_hash"]
    SaasySimple.config.model.activate( params['token'], params['id'] )
  end
end
```

My entire new file, placed in lib/monkeys/sassysimple.rb, reads

```
module SaasySimple
  class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
    def activate
      if Digest::MD5.hexdigest(params["security_data"] + SaasySimple.config.secret) == params["security_hash"]
        SaasySimple.config.model.activate( params['token'], params['id'], params['productname'] )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This isn't working - I'm still getting an error of `subscriptions#activate (ArgumentError) "wrong number of arguments (2 for 3)"`, which I believe is caused because my user method (see below) is expecting `productname` but not getting it from the un-monkeypatched version. Can someone tell me why putting the file in lib isn't working? Thanks!

This is the user method:

```
  def self.activate(token, id, productname)
    user = User.find( id )
    user.token = token
    user.status = 'active'
    user.package = productname
    user.save!
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the monkeypatch in an config/initializers/sassysimple.rb

Comment: Then try creating a new controller that extends SaasySimple::SubscriptionsController with your method

Comment: Also, not sure if extending ApplicationController works in a monkey patch, it's unnecessary tho

Comment: The new controller idea was a good one - I put the code in `class ActivationsController < SaasySimple::SubscriptionsController`. But it didn't solve the problem - still getting `An ArgumentError occurred in subscriptions#activate:

 wrong number of arguments (2 for 3)

.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/bundler/gems/SaasySimple-c41847cc58ac/app/controllers/saasy_simple/subscriptions_controller.rb:8:in `activate'`

Comment: Did you monkeypatch `SaasySimple.config.model.activate` to take the 3 arguments? Because that is what the error is about.

Comment: I think the config.model bit just points to the User model (there is a  `@model = User` in the SaasySimple initializer which sets this up). I have the code in the User model as I've written it above, which looks like it should take three parameters to me.

Answer (score 0):

- Have you verified that the controller really sees all three params?
- Is `User#activate` called anywhere else in the code? e.g. grep for it.

Comment: No, user#activate is only called by SaasySimple. How would I verify the first question? I can see that they're being sent in by the Post request made by SaaSy, which is then handled by the SubscriptionsController and sent on to the user model (or not, in this case).